# how to escape '&' in maven pom property values

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

I need to set a URL via a maven property (to be replaced per profile). The problem is that this URL contains some `&` and maven doesn't like this (if URL contains &_program):

> "The reference to entity "_program" must end with the ';' delimiter." error occurs in pom on this line.

So how to escape this character or how to escape a hole line that might contain some "special" characters. (What other characters are forbidden in property-values?)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've not used maven but from the sounds of it, standard XML escaping would get the job done.  In your case you can try using

`&amp;`  instead of `&`

[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 46):

You can escape one character or a whole line that might contain some "special" characters by surrounding property value with `<![CDATA[ property value ]]>`. For example for some URL it would look like:

```
<properties>
    <some.url><![CDATA[http://stackoverflow.com?param_1=1&param_2=2]]></some.url>
</properties>
```

Comment: The approach didn't work for a maven password property.